# How can I change Unity sidebar to bottom?

Tags: themes

How can I make changes to my sidebars to bottom, and the theme etc.

thank you

Comment: You may like [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/tweak-ubuntu-unity-get-a-dock-style-launcher-and-unity-dash/) as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this tool can do the job.

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/02/introducing-unity-tweak-tool